# What is the right way to manage the hugo project in GitHub?

Tags: github, repository, jekyll, hugo

I currently have `[username]/github.io` pages made with simple HTML/CSS.

Now I am trying to switch to Hugo to manage the sites more efficiently.
I understand that the Hugo (the static site generator) generates `public` directory which I can just copy the contents to `[username]/github.io` repository.

However, in this way, I have to have two different repositories to keep the Hugo project itself and the website that had generated.

What would be the correct way to keep the repositories for Hugo?

I believe in Jekyll, the pushed project will generate the github.io pages in the server side of GitHub.

For the Hugo projects, should I have to have two different repositories, one for the Hugo and the other for the generated sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need two repositories, one for Hugo’s content, and a second one that will be a git submodule with the public folder’s content in it.

Check the Hugo docs [Host on Github Step-by-step Instructions:](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/#step-by-step-instructions)

1. Create a `<YOUR-PROJECT>` (e.g. blog) repository on GitHub. This repository will contain Hugo’s content and other source files.
2. Create a `<USERNAME>.github.io` GitHub repository. This is the repository that will contain the fully rendered version of your Hugo website.
3. `git clone <YOUR-PROJECT-URL> && cd <YOUR-PROJECT>`
4. Make your website work locally (hugo server or hugo server -t ) and open your browser to http://localhost:1313.
5. Once you are happy with the results:

   `Press Ctrl+C to kill the server`

   `rm -rf public` to completely remove the public directory
6. `git submodule add -b master git@github.com:<username>/<username>.github.io.git public`. This creates a git submodule. Now when you run the hugo command to build your site to public, the created public directory will have a different remote origin (i.e. hosted GitHub repository). You can automate some of these steps with the following script.